# Silverlight DatePicker binding broken - what can I do to fix this?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I have a very simple binding problem with a DatePicker that is eluding me.

I have a ListBox bound to a list of objects with a DateTime property. I have an editing portion of my page for changing the selected item. This works fine - when I update the date in the DatePicker, the ListBox shows my updated date.

However, when I then select another item, the DatePicker control incorrectly updates the Date on the new item as well.

Here's my code:

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace BindingTest
{
    public partial class MainPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var vm = new ViewModel();
            DataContext = vm;
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            List = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

            for (var n = 0; n < 10; n++)
                List.Add(new Item { Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(n) });
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Item> List { get; set; }

        private Item _selectedItem;
        public Item SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set { _selectedItem = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem"); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }

    public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private DateTime _date;
        public DateTime Date
        {
            get { return _date; }
            set { _date = value; OnPropertyChanged("Date"); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"  x:Class="BindingTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List}" 
                 DisplayMemberPath="Date"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <TextBlock Text="Date:" />
            <sdk:DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the easiest way to solve this is to delay the change of selection so that the DatePicker updates the correct binding before the selection is changed.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I have a datagrid with a column that holds datepickers (by way of celltemplate). The datagrid is automatically sorted by the date, at which point other rows get changed to the newly entered value as well. Sounds like the same bug. I delayed the sort method with a DispatcherTimer, but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar bug occuring in a Silverlight 3 project (see my comment in Craig's answer). After a lot of trial and error, creating an extended DatePicker solved the issue for me. Doesn't win the pretty-prize, but I guess a subclass of a mess can be expected to be a mess.

DataBinding in xaml:

```
<local:EvdDatePicker SelectedDateEx="{Binding ViewModelProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

DatePicker extension:

```
/// <summary>
/// Databinding on DatePicker.SelectedDate is seriously messed up (maybe because of synchronization with 
/// Text property?). This class extends the DatePicker and provides another property (SelectedDateEx)
/// to bind to. This offers decoupling and a backup of the date value that can be reverted to.
/// Additionally, selected date (of any EvdDatePicker instance) may only be changed at a defined interval.
/// </summary>
public class EvdDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    // allow changes only every half second (adjust if necessary)
    private static TimeSpan _changeLock = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);

    // holds date of last user change
    private static DateTime _lastChange;

    public EvdDatePicker()
    {
        this.SelectedDateChanged += new EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(EvdDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Catch cases where SelectedDate gets changed by mistake
    /// </summary>
    void EvdDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // measures if the change is likely caused by unwanted chain reactions
        if (_lastChange < DateTime.Now.Subtract(_changeLock))
        {
            this.SelectedDateEx = e.AddedItems.Count > 0 ? (DateTime?)e.AddedItems[0] : null;
            _lastChange = DateTime.Now; // store last change time
        }

        // reject change (revert to old value), if the values are not synchronized by now
        if (this.SelectedDate != this.SelectedDateEx)
            this.SelectedDate = this.SelectedDateEx;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Bind to this property instead of SelectedDate
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime? SelectedDateEx
    {
        get { return (DateTime?)GetValue(SelectedDateExProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedDateExProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateExProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDateEx", typeof(DateTime?), typeof(EvdDatePicker), 
                                    new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectedDateExChanged)));

    private static void OnSelectedDateExChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        EvdDatePicker p = (EvdDatePicker)d;

        // initial binding, propagate to SelectedDate property
        DateTime? newValue = (DateTime?)e.NewValue;
        if (p.SelectedDate != newValue)
            p.SelectedDate = newValue;
    }
}
```